# Loading View into <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Just wondering if anyone knows of a decent jQuery plugin (Or Javascript) that would allow me to load "view" (NOT PARTIAL VIEW) into a `<div>` when a user clicks on a link.

Here's where it may be tricky, I have 8 pages.I have a Homepage in that, there is 3 divisions. First division for Header and second one have picture and third one for footer. I want to load view into second division. I have been searching Google and have not been able to find anything that seems stable.

Thanks in advance  Shiyas :)

### I have tried below code. It's not working.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#a_book_id").click(function () {
            $("#middleDiv").load("http://localhost:56708/Home/Books");
            });
    </script> 

</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
     <div id="headerDiv">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Header.cshtml")
     </div>
    <div id="middleDiv">        

    </div>
    <div id="footerDiv">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Footer.cshtml")
    </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

This code is from my HomePage. In here I am rendering Header(Partial view) into the first divison. When i click on a link in Header, the book view should load into middle division. Well, It's not loading.

Comment: Put whatever content you want to load into an html file and use `$.load();`

Comment: Check the error in console, or in network tab

Answer (score 2):

Place the piece of your script that loads the view at the bottom of your page just before `</body>`. You should also use a relative URL, so when you release to production you will not have to change this. Try the below.

```
<body>
<div id="mainDiv">
     <div id="headerDiv">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Header.cshtml")
     </div>
    <div id="middleDiv">        

    </div>
    <div id="footerDiv">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Footer.cshtml")
    </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#a_book_id").click(function () {
            $("#middleDiv").load("/Home/Books");
         });
    </script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jquery` `load` function.

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

```
$('#divId').load('url');
```

[jQuery .load() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)